# Can we override "Another app is displaying over chrome error" using javascript/typescript?

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, google-chrome

Is it possible to override "Another app is displaying over chrome error" using JavaScript/TypeScript?

**Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had faced *"Another App Is Displaying Over Chrome"* issue for couple of weeks. But finally I found a solution.
I disabled `"quick ball"` feature in my android and that's it. Problem got resolved!
and I also want to mention a great resource that helped me in solving this issue.

**You guys should check out [(Solved) Another App Is Displaying Over Chrome](https://magnifiedtech.com/another-app-is-displaying-over-chrome/)**

> **Disable Touch ball / quick ball feature**
> The quick ball feature is causing this issue. If you have enabled this feature knowingly or unknowingly, just disable it. The problem of “another app is displaying over chrome” will be resolved.

This article also includes:

> **Solution for Xiaomi Redmi note 7** 
>
> **Solution for Redmi 9s** 
>
> **Solution for OnePlus 6T** 
>
> **Solution for Xiaomi Poco F1** 
>
> **Solution for REDMI NOTE 8 PRO**